# Sorting through a delimited string with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a script that checks if a certain value is in a comma delimited string, and if the value is present, it should return true else it should return false.

Basically, I am trying to check if a user has voted for a specific person before, and if so, they cannot vote again, if they have not, vote and then add their uid to the database.

I am using explode to get all the values into an array, but I am unsure about the checking function, I have a few ideas but this is quite an important script so I wanted to see if there is a better way of going about it.

```
$test = "john,jack,tom";

$exploded = explode(",",$test);

$hostID = "john";

foreach($exploded as $one){
    if($one == $hostID){
        $return = TRUE;
    }else{
        $return = FALSE;
    };
};
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: do you store person ids in the database in that comma-separated form?

Comment: I store their names, yes, no need to store ID's for this specific app.

Comment: you should store id's and **in the separate rows** of another table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You could use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).
- Some people prefer to use lowercase `true` and `false`.
- The semicolon after `}` is not needed
- `$return = TRUE` does not actually stop the function. Maybe you do `return $return`.
- Some people like to put spaces after comma's and keywords (e.g. foreach, if, else)
- Some people prefer single quotes over double quotes

Code:

```
function find_name($name, $list)
{
    $exploded = explode(',', $list);
    return in_array($name, $exploded);
}

var_dump(find_name('john', 'john,jack,tom'));
?>
```

Comment: Good advice. The code, as it stands, is flawed in that it will still set the value of `$return` to `false` if the `$hostID` is not the last element in the array (as any subsequent checks will change the value).

Comment: Changing the boolean keywords to lowercase is a matter of personal preference. They are [case-insensitive](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). Personally, I find them easier to read in Uppercase and thus disagree to this particular advice.

Comment: I agree with Gordon on that one, I also prefer having them uppercase, it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

- [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) — Find position of first occurrence of a string

instead:

```
 return strpos('john,jack,tom', 'barney'); // returns FALSE
```

Note that the function returns the position if the string was found, so searching for *john* will return zero, which would be `FALSE` if you compare it for equality (`==`). In other words use the identity comparator (`===`).

As Lucanos correctly points out, there is chance to get false positives when using strpos if the searched name is part of a longer name, e.g. searching for *jean* only would also find *jean-luc*. You could add a comma at the end of the haystack string and search for *jean,* though, but then again, it feels hackish. So it's likely better to use `in_array`.

Comment: +1 for saving a lot of useless work if the string isn't there to begin with.

Comment: But `strpos()`, unless used as a preliminary check before doing an `in-array()` may return false positives. For instance `strpos( 'jean-paul,mark,steven' , 'jean' )` would return true.

Comment: @Lucanos that's true indeed. I'll add that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

As Sjoerd says, in his very good advice.

```
function find_name( $needle , $haystack ) {
  if( strpos( $haystack , $needle )===false )
    return false;
  return in_array( $needle , explode( ',' , $haystack ) );
}
```

Test cases:

```
// find_name( 'john' , 'peter,mark,john' );
true
// find_name( 'peter' , 'mark,john' );
false
```

EDITED: As per advice from Gordon.